# IRIS Decision Tree Classification Problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I wanted to write some simple classification on IRIS dataset and get the recall and precision score, followed a youtube video but when testing the accuracy it gives me 100. I have some assumption about what is wrong but don't know what to do . can you help me expand the code to make it better? and how to write a recall function for this version of the classification?

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris 
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 
import graphviz
from sklearn.tree import
   export_graphviz
    iris = load_iris() 
  x = iris.data  #feature   
y = iris.target
   #prediction 
  tree_clf =DecisionTreeClassifier()   
model = tree_clf.fit(x,y) #model_fitting  dot_data = export_graphviz
   (tree_clf,out_file=None,feature_names=iris.feature_names,class_names=iris.target_names,filled=True,rounded=True,special_characters=True)

   graph=graphviz.Source(dot_data) graph.render("iris")
   accuracy=tree_clf.score(x,y) 
print(accuracy)
```

Comment: The stack overflow question.answer editor has a code quotation feature - please use it. As it is, your code is impossible to read. Additionally, your request ("expand the code to make it better" is to vague. Be more specific, focused, and precise.

Answer (score 2):

For checking your results, you can use sklearn.metrics

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

print(classification_report(y, model.predict(x)))
```

```
 precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00        50
           1       1.00      1.00      1.00        50
           2       1.00      1.00      1.00        50

    accuracy                           1.00       150
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       150
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       150
```

If you have doubts about the result, check it visual.

```
print(model.predict(x))
```

Comment: thanks for the help  , but the ways model is just all 1.00 is not it weird? how can I expand on the code to not have this accuracy

Comment: On these data you have such result. And it is normal.

Comment: And for future  https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/. For  write questions.

Comment: and Can you elaborate on why this happens in this program?

Comment: Iris is data which have a good classification. In this picture you can see this classes with nice border. https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/430-4307573_png-iris-dataset-pca-transparent-png.png

Answer (score 1):

You are making a fundamental mistake in machine learning - evaluating a model on the data that was used to train it. Instead, you need to split your data into two sets - training and testing. Train your model on the training data, and evaluate on the testing data. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Try something like this:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y)
model = tree_clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
accuracy=tree_clf.score(x_test, y_test)
```

To see why this is a problem, consider the extreme case of a "cheating" model that just remembers the input data and outputs whatever it remembers. It will get 100% accuracy using your code, while having learned nothing.

Comment: if possible could you expand it on the code above? cause I'm having problems. writing some of the functions! thanks

Comment: Have a look at this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation

Answer (score 0):

So I implemented and changed according to the recommendation and implemented some of the source code I founded for the 150 data points (120 training and 30 testing) so the question I have is my classification report implementation correct or not ? tnx

---

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report



def accuracy(y_true,y_predict): 
    count=0;
    for i in range(0,len(y_true)):
        if y_true[i] == y_predict[i]:
            count=count+1;   
    return(count*100*1.0/len(y_true));



#reading trainning data
train_data=pd.read_csv("iris_train_data.csv",header=0)
x_train=train_data.values[:,0:4];
y_train=train_data.values[:,4];

#training the classifier 
clf=DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion= 'entropy');
clf.fit(x_train,y_train);

print('Depth of learnt tree is ',clf.tree_.max_depth)
#t=clf.get_n_leaves()
print('Number of leaf nodes in learnt tree is 9','\n')

#reading test data
test_data=pd.read_csv("iris_test_data.csv",header=0)
x_test=test_data.values[:,0:4];
y_test=test_data.values[:,4];

#Training accuracy and Test accuracy without pruning
print('Training accuracy of classifier is ',accuracy(y_train,clf.predict(x_train)))
print('Test accuracy using classifier is ',accuracy(y_test,clf.predict(x_test)),'\n')
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report



def accuracy(y_true,y_predict): 
    count=0;
    for i in range(0,len(y_true)):
        if y_true[i] == y_predict[i]:
            count=count+1;   
    return(count*100*1.0/len(y_true));
def pruning_by_max_leaf_nodes(t):
    for i in range(1, t-1):
        clfnxt1 = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion= 'entropy',max_leaf_nodes=t-i);
        clfnxt1.fit(x_train,y_train)
        print('Max_leaf_nodes = ',t-i,'Test Accuracy = ',accuracy(y_test,clfnxt1.predict(x_test)))    
    return;



def pruning_by_max_depth(t):
    for i in range(1, t):
        clfnxt2 = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion= 'entropy',max_depth=t-i);
        clfnxt2.fit(x_train,y_train)
        print('Max_depth = ',clfnxt2.tree_.max_depth,'Test Accuracy = ',accuracy(y_test,clfnxt2.predict(x_test))) 
    return;


#reading trainning data
train_data=pd.read_csv("iris_train_data.csv",header=0)
x_train=train_data.values[:,0:4];
y_train=train_data.values[:,4];

#training the classifier 
clf=DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion= 'entropy');
clf.fit(x_train,y_train);

print('Depth of learnt tree is ',clf.tree_.max_depth)
#t=clf.get_n_leaves()
print('Number of leaf nodes in learnt tree is 9','\n')

#reading test data
test_data=pd.read_csv("iris_test_data.csv",header=0)
x_test=test_data.values[:,0:4];
y_test=test_data.values[:,4];


#Pruning by reducing max_depth
print('Pruning case1:By reducing the max_depth of the tree')
pruning_by_max_depth(clf.tree_.max_depth)
print('')    
t=9;

#Pruning by reducing max_leaf_nodes
print('Pruning case2:By reducing the max_leaf_nodes of the tree')
pruning_by_max_leaf_nodes(t);

print(classification_report(y_test, clf.fit(x_train,y_train).predict(x_test)))
```